# how to load content on settimeout

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to delay .load and then load a different page of content?

The following code isn't working

```
   $(document).on('click', '#id', function() {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $('.overlay').load('loader.html');
          $('.overlay').show();
      }, 100);

          $('.overlay').load('page6.html');
         $('.overlay').show();  

    });
```

Comment: What exactly not working? It should show "page6.html" for 1/10 of a second then show "loader.html"

Comment: $(document).on('click', '#id', function() {
      setTimeout(function () {
          $('.overlay').load('loader.html');
          $('.overlay').show();
      }, 0);

          $('.overlay').load('page6.html');
         $('.overlay').show();  

    });

Answer (score 0):

Load is executed in async mode. You're probably trying to wait until load finished to show `.overlay`. In order to do that you should execute `show` inside complete handler

```
$('.overlay').load('page6.html', function() {
    $('.overlay').show();  
});
```

Comment: how can I delay the first .load and then execute then second .load?

Comment: @user1177860: what's the first? `loader.html`?